# ImageView that's like Instagram Stories avatar?

Tags: android, kotlin, instagram

I was wondering is it possible to reproduce Instagram Stories avatar, look and feel, including animations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently stumbled upon open-source lib that does just that!

https://github.com/vitorhugods/AvatarView

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!